# Laravel Eloquent delete by id

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to delete a single record by id. Instead, it deletes all records in that table.

Here's my code:

**View**

```
<form role="form" action="{{ route('status.delete', ['statusId' => $status->id]) }}" method="post">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default"><i class="fa fa-times"></i> Delete</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ Session::token() }}">
</form>
```

**Routes**

```
Route::post('/status/{statusId}/delete', [
    'uses' => '\Dashboard\Http\Controllers\StatusController@deleteStatus',
    'as' => 'status.delete',
    'middleware' => ['auth'],
]);
```

**Controller**

```
public function deleteStatus(Request $request, $statusId)
{
    Auth::user()->statuses()->delete($statusId);

    return redirect()->route('home')->with('success', 'Post deleted.');
}
```

**Note:** When I `dd($statusId)` it does provide the right ID for the status I'm deleting. So that part does work.

Comment: You can pass the id to `destroy` instead of `delete`. Destroy will ignore `deleting` and `deleted` events.

Comment: Also read: [How To Delete Record By ID using Laravel Eloquent](https://devnote.in/how-to-delete-record-by-id-using-laravel-eloquent/)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Unfortunately, the Eloquent builder does not support passing the id to `delete`.

Instead, you have to first find to model, then call `delete` on it:

```
$request->user()->statuses()->findOrFail($statusId)->delete();
```

Comment: Ah I understand now I thought you could pass the id to it, thanks for your help thats now working!

Answer (score 26):

This is possible in Laravel 5.6 using the destroy method:

From the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent#inserting-and-updating-models):

> However, if you know the primary key of the model, you may delete the
>   model without retrieving it. To do so, call the destroy method

```
App\Model::destroy(1);
```

or to delete an array of ids:

```
App\Model::destroy([1, 2, 3]);
```

or by query:

```
App\Model::where('active', 0)->delete();
```

Comment: FYI, `destroy` still pulls the model from the DB before deleting it (so that it can fire the proper events).

Answer (score 2):

you can delete the model by using another approach like

```php
App\Models\ModelName::find(id)->delete()
```

but it throws `nullPointerException` that you have to handle

Answer (score 1):

```
**Step 1 create route inside web.php**

Route::delete('/answers_delete/{id}', [App\Http\Controllers\AnswerController::class, 'delete'])->name('answers.delete');

 **Step 2 Create method in your controller**
use App\Models\Answer; // use in top of this file
public function delete($id)
    {
        $ans = Answer::find($id);
        $ans->delete();
        session()->flash('success', 'Answer Deleted Successfully!!!');
        return view('admin.anser.index');
    }

**Step 3 define your route name inside form action(Note my case view file name index.blade.php and inside admin/answer/index.blade.php)*

<form action="{{ route('answers.delete', $answer->id) }}" method="POST">
  @csrf
  @method('DELETE')
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger" style="display: inline;">Delete</button>
</form>
```